# How do I convert BLOB into VARCHAR in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, blob, varchar

It is in a shared host and I access with Navicat. I have field with BLOB and I want to convert it into VARCHAR. I've tried in the design screen but everything was lost. I backed up.

Answer (score 30):

try using this, I found it some time ago, you can convert it to `char`, not to `Varchar2` or `Varchar`, haven't test it yet. Try:

```
CAST(a.ar_options AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8)
```

MySQL treat data unique. Hence there is a difference between Blob and Text. Text simply means a text string stored as original, not in binary, whereas a blob is a text string stored as a binary.

Comment: How do I specify the target table and field?

Comment: table CAST(item AS CHAR(10000> char lenght) CHARACTER SET utf8)

Comment: or you can convert the data as this   CONVERT(blobname USING latin1), there you got it as plain text

Comment: You should use `utf8mb4` instead of `utf8`.

Answer (score 2):

try with the below query

```
alter table table_name change field_name field_name VARCHAR(1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this of MySQL's Website if you are trying to change your column to a different data type and keep the new data type in the database. Works great for what I need!

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE col col1 varchar(100)
```