# Create table from two rows, one column

Tags: sql, create-table

I am trying to create a graph using two different rows from the same column.

The first row (the y-axis) is fine.

```
SELECT box_value FROM my_table WHERE box_value=42 AND box_id=250
```

represents the x-axis.

The second row (the x-axis)

```
SELECT box_value FROM my_table WHERE box_id=250
```

is not fine because I can't use ‘SELECT’ in the same procedure to call this second row!

What I'm trying to achieve is -

```
box_id=250  | box_value=42
--------------------------
45          | 42
63          | 42
70          | 42
54          | 42
45          | 42
```

It does not seem to me that it can be done in SQL

Am I right?

Or are you a genius willing to help?

Comment: Can you show more of your procedure?  I do not see any issue with making 2 calls to the same table within a single procedure.

Comment: Making calls to the same table in a single procedure is not a problem at all. Can you provide some context as to why you are saying it does not work?
I have given an answer from what I originally thought your question was, however, I feel I may have interpreted it incorrectly at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by performing a `join` on the two values.  Note that you are returning more than one row, so you can't do this as nested subqueries in the `select` clause:

```
select x.box_value as x, y.box_value as y
from (SELECT box_value
      FROM my_table
      WHERE box_id = 250
     ) x cross join
     (SELECT box_value
      FROM my_table
       WHERE box_value = 42 AND box_id = 250
     ) y;
```

I do want to note that the `y` value is constant, so you could also do:

```
select x.box_value as x, 42 as y
from (SELECT box_value
      FROM my_table
      WHERE box_id = 250
     ) x
```

Comment: Wow! That was perfect, you created two columns from two rows and filtered the output for each row, that was exactly what I was looking for. But, it through up an error on the second column requiring the column to be numerical, it is fact BLOB! ...is it possible to convert BLOB to numerical?

Comment: Storing numbers in a blob column seems like a really bad idea and is not anything I've ever done.  You can try `convert()`, perhaps converting to a string first and then to a number.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff Gave you +1 because your answer was useful for the OP, he was just too lazy to pick an accepted answer.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I'm not lazy, just don't automatically assume that everyone knows their way around this brilliant service. I was unable to vote you up because I do not have enough reputation (15). I then made an incorrect assumption that I would not be able to select the correct answer. Thanks again for your answer, it has made life much easier and productive for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM (
(SELECT ... FROM my_table WHERE ...) as Column_1_name,
(SELECT ... FROM my_table WHERE ...) as Column_2_name
)
```

The above should help you :)

Comment: Thanks Lawrence. I have two rows in one column. Row A = "length" and Row B = "Horse Power". I want to return all Row A values WHERE B=42. There is now another issue in that ‘B’ is of the type BLOB but it must be converted to numeric.

Comment: As Gordon suggested, you can convert from blob to char to int. I found the following stack overflow on how to convert from blob to char.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627621/how-do-i-convert-blob-into-varchar-in-mysql

Don't forget, if you found the answer useful, please upvote it or mark it as the accepted answer.