# GROUP_CONCAT cut error on view when creating to table

Tags: mysql, view, group-concat

I have a view defined as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view 
AS SELECT some_table.some_id AS id,
SUBSTRING(GROUP_CONCAT(some_table.value), 1, 1000) AS other_field 
FROM some_table 
WHERE some_table.some_other_id = 5 GROUP BY some_table.some_id;
```

If I query the whole table, I get all the expected results, truncated to 1000 characters.

However, if I try to do:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table SELECT * FROM my_view LIMIT 1;
```

I get the error:

```
Row 254468 was cut by GROUP_CONCAT()
```

Checking `CHAR_LENGTH` of each `other_field` shows they are all 1000 characters or fewer.

`group_concat_max_len` is currently set to 200,000.

Why does the `CREATE TABLE` give the error, but the `SELECT * ...` by itself not?

---

```
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `some_other_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `some_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `value` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48190231 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: cast other_field as varchar 1000. and see if you still get the error on the table create.  What does the view define as the data type for other_field (I'm guessing the undefined datatype blob or lack of precision/scale is causing a problem on the create table.  Likely the size is being set smaller due to sampling it does.  When create table runs it samples some of the data so the field may be set to a smaller size on the smaller sample when a larger size is needed.  By being explicit on casting to varchar(1000) you eliminate this issue from the sampling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify view to...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW my_view 
AS SELECT some_table.some_id AS id,
cast(substring(GROUP_CONCAT(some_table.value),1,1000) as char(1000)) AS other_field 
FROM some_table 
WHERE some_table.some_other_id = 5 
GROUP BY some_table.some_id;
```

or alter the create table to select fields individually and cast other_field to varchar(1000).

What I believe is happening is the sampling the engine does to evaluate what datatype and size to use for the table only samples a few of the rows.  Size may be larger on later records causing the insert to fail.  To resolve explicitly define the column size for the concatenated field.  By default I believe the engine will use blob in the view which makes it ok; but the create table samples the data to try and determine data type and since size isn't blob; I believe it's trying to create a varchar data type but sizes it incorrectly

Comment: 1) It seems to need to be `char(1000)` rather than `varchar(1000)`. I don't think `cast` takes `varchar`. 2) Now I'm getting the error `Truncated incorrect CHAR(1000) value`.

Comment: odd char just pads spaces to end to keep constant length of 1000.  varchar doesn't pad spaces so you can have length of 1 to 1000...  But you seem to be correct... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627621/how-do-i-convert-blob-into-varchar-in-mysql  may need to put the substring back in... but I can't see why.. you said they were all < 1000 when combined right?

Comment: could it be a language/collation issue?  What is the DDL for some_table showing collation and language?

Comment: Added that to the question.

Comment: Running out of ideas.  I thought for sure it was the issue with the casting of other_field to character data type. ... Limit 1 w/o an order by seems logically incorrect? `CREATE TABLE my_table SELECT * FROM my_view order by some_ID LIMIT 1;`  My next steps would be to start removing pieces of information to see what could be causing the issue.  Is there a sample data set I could play w/ on a SQLFiddle.com to recreate the error and try and debug or similar site?

Comment: Thank-you heaps for the suggestions! Unfortunately, adding the `order by` doesn't appear to help. I suspect it's because in order to do the `order by` it needs to evaluate the whole table.

Comment: Eventually found that there was some REALLY bogus data in the table.

Comment: Bad data gets you every time ;P

Comment: Wish I'd seen it earlier! Much earlier. Thanks for the help! :-)