# How to convert longblob data to varchar?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, blob

I want to convert longblob data to varchar or text.
Data saved in database like "[BLOB - 2 B]".
I want to convert this data.

How to fix it?

Comment: Follow the link: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627621/how-do-i-convert-blob-into-varchar-in-mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627621/how-do-i-convert-blob-into-varchar-in-mysql).

Comment: Not working any solutions.Can you please give me an another solutions or links?

Comment: Follow this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948174/how-do-i-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql

Comment: Is that for codeigniter sessions database?

Comment: If you are still having trouble, please provide `SELECT HEX(LEFT(blob_col, 10))` and some clue of what the characters should be.

Answer (score 2):

In mysql you can run:

```
select cast(column as char) from tablename
```

Or in php you can use mysql_fetch_object function to get object

Comment: Not working this query.Can you please give me an another solutions or links?

Answer (score 0):

Data saved in BLOB datatype in MySQL, can not be used to read the value directly. Instead, you can type-cast the datatype into some specified character set and then read value from it.

For example:-

In DOCUMENT table, DESCRIPTION field is of BLOB datatype.
Then to read the data in MySQL you can cast it like e-g

```
SELECT CAST(DESCRIPTION AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8) FROM DOCUMENT;
```

`CAST(DESCRIPTION AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8`  will convert the BLOB datatype into character set which can be read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CONVERT function :

```
SELECT CONVERT(column USING utf8) FROM table;
```

as explained in another post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948174/how-do-i-convert-from-blob-to-text-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

If your blob file is just a text file then, just normal query should do the job.

```
$query = $this->db->select('column_name_that_blob_data')->from('table_name')->get();
var_dump($query->result());
```